# How to check if Openfire is running?

Tags: services, aws

I know that Openfire 3.7.1 is installed because when i run;

```
apt-cache policy openfire
```

That confirms it. But when I try;

```
/etc/init.d/openfire start
```

The line resets like a successful command. If I browse to port 9090, It wont connect. I verified that opening the ports is working in AWS by installing apache.

- How can I check if openfire is running?
- Is there a separate issue why openfire doesn't run?
- Is there a log I can check?

Comment: Did you try checking it using `sudo netstat -tpan` to see if port 9090 is being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also try :

```
sudo ps -ef | grep openfire
```

This will show that the process is running and also show the symlink as well with the absolute path of the openfire installation.

Answer (score 1):

Use status to check:

```
systemctl status openfire.service
```

or:

```
sudo service openfire status
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can get this [init.d file](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/1ad09b1f690320981f188822ab87b12b7c5f24c6/build/debian/openfire.init.d) I've proposed for merge and see if it works for you (works on debian). I basically added a status function. You can then check with the usual `/etc/init.d/openfire status`, you should get something like this :

```
root@app-server[192.168.100.83] ~ # /etc/init.d/openfire status
best java alternative in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
openfire is not running
root@app-server[192.168.100.83] ~ # /etc/init.d/openfire start
best java alternative in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Starting openfire: openfire.
root@app-server[192.168.100.83] ~ # /etc/init.d/openfire status
best java alternative in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
openfire is running with pid 21048
root@app-server[192.168.100.83] ~ #
```